# Do I need to apply for a visa to enter South Korea during my 13-hour layover?

Tags: visas, myanmar-citizens

I am from Myanmar and I will go to Mongolia to attend AMCDRR 2018. I will depart from  Yangon at 11:30 pm on June 30, 2018 and arrive in South Korea at 7:30 am on July 1. I will have a layover of about 13 hours in South Korea. Do I need a visa to go out of the airport during my layover?

Answer (score 2):

According to the maintained [Wikipedia page on the visa policy of South Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#30-day_visa_exemption) you only can get a visa-free entry on your passport if it's a non-ordinary (eg diplomatic) passport.

[VisaHQ](https://www.visahq.com/south-korea/requirements/myanmar/resident-united-states/) also confirms you'd need a visa to enter the country.